# Which part of my query is wrong? UNNEST function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I couldn't figure out which part of my code is wrong.
I used a UNNEST function but the error msg is still
'Cannot access field productSKU on a value with type ARRAY>' in Google Bigquery.

My query is below:

```sql
SELECT 
hits.product.productSKU AS product_SKU, 
hits.product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name, 
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) AS Total_Revenue, 
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits  
WHERE 
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170731' AND totals.transactions >= 1
Group by
hits.product.productSKU
Order by
v2ProductName DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the overall logic of your query reflect what you want to achieve - below is correct version that fixes unnest'ing part as well as adds missing field in group by - hope you see what gets corrected

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  product.productSKU AS product_SKU, 
  product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name, 
  SUM(totals.transactionRevenue) AS Total_Revenue, 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hit,  
  UNNEST(hit.product) AS product  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170731' AND totals.transactions >= 1
GROUP BY product_SKU, Product_Name
ORDER BY v2ProductName DESC
```